# Azure kubernetes - mount Azure blob as a volume and write using python?

Tags: python, azure, kubernetes, azure-blob-storage, persistent-volumes

I am trying to monut a persistent volume using Azure blob storage and write a a file using python application. Is there any sample available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Azure Blobs Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/blobs/) is an *object storage* solution that is accessible via an REST API.

There is an [client for Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python) with a good quick start guide to follow.